# Is there an (attempted) complete list of organizations that have barred Taiwan from joining or participating with them, in order to appease China?

Tags: china, reference-request, taiwan

The Taipei Times's June 11, 2013 [Taiwan group barred from French event to due to China](https://www.taipeitimes.com/News/front/archives/2023/06/11/2003801343) begins:

> An overseas Taiwanese association is seeking public support after it was denied access to a cultural festival set to be held in September in Lyon, France, because of pressure from China.
>
> The Association Culturelle des Taiwanais de Lyon (ACTL), which promotes Taiwan globally, said that the organizer of the Fete des Bannieres du Monde — the festival of world banners — denied its application to participate after Chinese participants threatened to withdraw if Taiwan was allowed entry.

Another more visible and notable example would be the "kicking out" of [Taiwan (with observer status) from the World Health Organization in 2016](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taiwan_and_the_World_Health_Organization).

Note that this is a [reference-request](/questions/tagged/reference-request) question - I'm asking:

**Question:** Is there *something like* a central list of organizations that have barred Taiwan from joining or participating with them, in order to appease China that makes a significant effort to be complete?

Comment: related: [Did the organizer of the Fete des Bannieres du Monde deny Taiwan's application to participate after Chinese participants threatened to withdraw?](https://politics.stackexchange.com/q/79908/16047)

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it appears to be asking for a list and there are likely to be many different lists that would meet the needs.

Comment: @JoeW No, there is nothing off-topic about a [reference-request](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/reference-request) question that asks for a list. There aren't a lot of reference-request questions here (only 117) so you may not be familiar with them. This is not a "list question" asking for readers to list things, this is asking for a single resource. That's perfectly on-topic.

Comment: You are asking for a random list of which there are likely many of and it makes it hard to find a good answer if any one of the many lists could be it.

Comment: @JoeW I don't see "random" anywhere, your choice of the word "random" seems itself random. That there is already a [good answer](https://politics.stackexchange.com/a/79924/16047) providing a link to a good, non-random list assembled by an undeniably not-random, government source, this is also not a valid complaint. Now, what will your *next* angle of attack be?

Comment: All I was trying to say is that there are many lists out there that fit your needs and it comes down to you picking the one you like the best.

Comment: @JoeW that's the nature of a [reference-request](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/reference-request) question, there can be more than one reference that fits the description. We don't vote to close reference-request questions that can have more than one answer. We don't vote to close ANY Stack Exchange on the grounds that it can have more than one answer, so long as it doesn't stray into long lists, and even then some are acceptable. Have you actually found a second, and third list to justify your "there are many lists out there that fit your needs" or are you just guessing?

Comment: Users are free to vote for reasons that they feel justified and don't need others to tell them that they are wrong.

Comment: Voted not to close as it can be answered factually.

Comment: @JoeW sure, and once they leave a "because it appears to be asking for a list and there are likely to be many different lists that would meet the needs" comment, others are free to respond to it, especially when no examples are provided to support "likely to be many".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, it's right here: [Taiwan Ministry of Foreign Affairs: Instances of China's Interference with Taiwan's International Presence](https://en.mofa.gov.tw/cl.aspx?n=1510)

Comment: That appears to be a partial list that doesn't include everything that the OP is looking for.

Comment: @JoeW well I'm the OP and it's *exactly the kind of list* I was looking for. Everything from birdwatching organizations to blocking Wikimedia from the General Assembly of the World Intellectual Property Organization because of its Taiwan-related content. I quickly regretted putting the phrase "central, comprehensive" in the title but now that JamesK's answer drills down on that wording, I can't really edit the question.

Comment: @uhoh you may be happy with the list but that doesn't mean it is a comprehensive list like your question was asking for. And I am guessing there are lots of lists like this out there.

Comment: @JoeW there is the spirit of the law and the letter of the law, (and never the twain shall meet, but that's a separate thing) [JamesK froze that phrase by basing an answer on it rather than leaving a helpful comment that it over-constrained the problem](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/79907/is-there-something-like-a-central-comprehensive-list-of-organizations-that-have/79924?noredirect=1#comment345419_79913) I can't ask a 2nd, separate question for a list that's not necessarily "central comprehensive" (would be closed as duplicate)